# Tishrei Pilgrimage

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe, breslov, tishrei

Thousands of Breslovers go to Uman for Tishrei, and thousands of Lubavitchers go to Crown Heights for Tishrei.
I'm curious if there's (nowadays) any other 'mass pilgrimages' among any other Jewish communities by Tishrei.

(Edit: I mean nowadays and to one place, not like a lot of Jews going to a lot of places like tashlich)

Comment: There's the traditional Jewish one: Go to Jerusalem for Pesach, Shavuot and Sukkot.

Comment: Yes, there is. Thousands of Jews throughout the world make a pilgrimage to their local synagogue or temple for 3 days of the whole year. That's an accomplishment that they're proud of! (It would be nice to see them most of the other 382 days of 5776, but those 3 days are a good start!)

Comment: @DanF and by some it's just yom Kippur. They should try purim or simchas torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA I THINK the OP meant, currently. Nowadays, many Jews seem to make their Passover pilgrimages to Miami Beach or Disney World.

Comment: Curious - do a significant number of Israeli and non-North American Lubavitchers come to 770 for Tishrei? Is it for just RH and YK or for Succot too? Has this increased or decreased after the Rebbe's death?

Comment: @DanF Many of the ones (who care about traditional Judaism) go to Jerusalem.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's good to know. Bezrat Hashem, my family and I can increase that stat soon.

Comment: @DanF Yes, large amount of non American people go to 770 for Tishrei, including sukkos. Most people in my Yeshivah are going. I wasn't there before the Rebbe's histalkus, so I can't tell you if it's increased our decreased, but it's still packed to the brim. (You asked about sukkos, in crown heights is one of the largest of not the largest simchas beis hashoevah celebration in the world.)

Comment: Can you clarify what factors distinguish Tashlich from the examples you brought? In fact, why not just specify clearly the relevant parameters, instead of using vague words and ambiguous comparisons?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, tashlich is to a million different places, not thousands of people to one place.

Comment: @user613 Why not edit these parameters in your question. It looks like there are two - 1) Many Jews going to the SAME singular geographic place and 2) specifically during the month of Tishrei. Perhaps you also mean 3) Currently (not historically, such as *aliya l'regel*.

Comment: Any major Chasiduth; e.g. thousands of Gerer Chasidim go to ger to the Rebbe for each Chag and often for random Shabatot.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every Chasidic court will have most of its male Chasidim (and sometimes entire families) come to the Rebbe for Yom Tov.

Belz has over 7,000 families, for example, most of which will try be in Kiryat Belz in Jerusalem for special days. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belz_(Hasidic_dynasty)#Belz_today)). My guess would be some 30,000 males converging there.

While not a clear-cut case of *Jewish communities* per se, many Yeshivot have thousands of Alumni who come pray at their Alma Mater for Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippour. Examples would include [Ponevezh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponevezh_Yeshiva) in Bnei Brak, and [Chevron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebron_Yeshiva) and [Kol Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_Torah) in Jerusalem.

<sup>By the way, I object to your use of the word pilgrimage to go to a cemetery in Uman for Yom Tov. **Pilgrimage** is defined as:</sup>
<sup>1. A journey made to a sacred place, or a religious journey.</sup>
<sup>2. by extension A visit to any site revered or associated with a meaningful event.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain what you mean by "pilgrimages" and if that includes any type of mass gathering at any place whatsoever. I see that you did limit it to Tishrei.

So, the most "obvious" one I can think of is that numerous people gather at a body of water usually on the 1st day of Rosh Hashanna for *Tashlich*.

If this was not your definition, please clarify this in your question.

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: @user613 Not really. You just excluded one case. It's not any more clear what you want.